# Win Error 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, directory

I can't understan why i recive WinError 123 in the following filepath using my code below. I have used the same code as others but for me it will not work:

```
target_dir = "./models/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
```

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: './models/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5'
```

Comment: I think `target_dir` needs to be an f-string. Add an `f` before the string: `target_dir = f"./models/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
target_dir = f"./models/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
  os.mkdir(target_dir)
```

read more about `f-strings` in python on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/)

Comment: '
  File "<ipython-input-184-9c455a077ea6>", line 1, in <module>
    target_dir = f"./models/weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5"

NameError: name 'epoch' is not defined'

Comment: It gives me this error.

Comment: It means you didn't have any variable named epoch. What is epoch supposed to be in your code? And what is the actual file name ( exactly the way it is in your local disk). If it's exactly like the one in your question, then you need to rename the file